Destructuring props with default values
In Svelte 5 I need to do:
let { foo = 42, bar = 58 } = $props();

to extract the values sent by props with default values. How can I do the same when bar depends on the value of foo, like:
// does not work:
let { foo = 42, bar = foo + 1 } = $props();


At a basic JS destructuring level, you can't.

The generated code look like it should work to me, maybe this should be reported as an issue. I guess the fallback is only evaluated once but not inside an effect...

Opened an issue for this.

You will probably need multiple steps and $derived, e.g.
const props = $props();
const { foo = 42, bar = props.foo + 1 } = $derived(props);

This will not take any default for foo into account when setting bar, for that you need to split it further, e.g.
const props = $props();
const { foo, bar } = $derived.by(() => {
    const foo = props.foo ?? 42;
    const bar = props.bar ?? (foo + 1);
    return { foo, bar };
});


Thanks, before accepting I'll see if the issue you raised get an official answer, thanks for raising the issue!

Current behavior was deemed intentional, which I pretty much expected. It is probably also not that common of a use case.

Well in my case I wanted to define mostly a default value based on other values… The main issue is that it is a $bindable() prop as well… but I ended up using a different solution in my case.
